# Внедрение зависимости в PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Есть сервис(MyService.php) для которого я пишу тест, но в свою очередь этот сервис зависит от репозитория (MyRepository.php). Сделал так, создал Mock для репозитория и внедрил его в тест, но проблема в том что сервис вызывает метод репозитория, который должен вернуть результат из бд. Как быть в таком случае(т.е. проблема возникает в случае, когда нужно вызвать метод `getData`)?

**MyServiceTest.php**

```
class MyServiceTest extends TestCase
{
    public $myRepository;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->myRepository = \Mockery::mock(MyRepository::class);
    }

    public function testFirst()
    {
        $service = new MyService(
            $this->myRepository
        );

        $chainsList = $service->getData($coin);
...
```

**MyService.php**

```
class MyService
{
     public $myRepository;

     public function __construct($myRepository)
     {
        $this->myRepository = $myRepository;
     }

     public function getData()
     {
        return $this->myRepository->getDataInDb();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ответ выше почти то что вам нужно. Только надо было указать какие методы НЕ надо мокать - они и будут реально вызваны

```
$this->myRepository = $this->getMockBuilder(MyRepository::class)->setMethodsExcept('getDataInDb')->getMock();
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `$this->createMock()`, который в Ларе создает мок объект, в котором можно определить что нужно возвращать. Посмотрите как она реализована в коде Лары.

А используется так:

```
$this->myRepository = $this->createMock(MyRepository::class);
$this->myRepository->method("getDataInDb")->willReturn(/** подготовленная коллекция данных */);
```

Кроме `willRewturn` есть и другие варианты возврата из заглушки, в том числе вызов родных методов. Подробнее написано в [справке](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/test-doubles.html)